# I cannot get the led to blink 6 times, then terminate the program in C

Tags: c, pic, terminate

Why doesn't exit() work with the PIC16f877?

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <pic16f877.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4e6

int main(void){
    int count;
    int max_count = 6;
    TRISD = 0xBF;
    for (count=0; count<max_count; ++count){
        PORTD   = 0x40;
        __delay_ms(500);
        PORTD   = 0x00;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Error message:

```
Error   [482] lab1_home.obj; 20. symbol "_exit" is defined more than once in "startup.obj"
Error   [482] lab1_home.obj; 20. symbol "_exit" is defined more than once in "startup.obj"
```

And what are the reasons that these code programs build successfully, but keep the led blinking forever?

### Attempt1:

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <pic16f877.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4e6

void main(void){
    int count;
    int max_count = 6;
    TRISD = 0xBF;
    for (count=0; count<max_count; ++count){
        PORTD   = 0x40;
        __delay_ms(500);
        PORTD   = 0x00;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    return;
}
```

### Attempt2:

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <pic16f877.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4e6

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    int max_count = 6;
    TRISD = 0xBF;
    do {
        count++;
        PORTD   = 0x40;
        __delay_ms(500);
        PORTD   = 0x00;
        __delay_ms(500);
    } while ( count != max_count );
    abort;
}
```

Is the loop not exiting? Or is the way I'm trying to terminate my program wrong? Also I've considered 1 thing else...does the WDT have anything to do with this loop repeating forever?

Comment: Your second loop doesn't initialize `count`, so it  has an indeterminate value.  This is why you have an infinite loop. The first problem is a multiply defined symbol.  Stick with the first version and figure out why `exit` is defined more than once (check your headers).  Lastly, you don't need to abort or exit explicitly; just let main complete.

Comment: Instead of exit(0); in int main() you can do return 0;

Comment: @AlexanderVX I tried the return(0) as well as return, but led keeps blinking.

Comment: If `exit` is defined more than once, that's a link issue. You've got two different binaries or libraries you are linking that include a definition of `exit`. Since you don' t show how you're compiling and linking, we can't tell in any more detail where that problem may lie. Also, you need to show how `PORTD` is defined. If it's a memory mapped address, then you may need `*PORTD = 0x40;` rather than `PORTD = 0x40;`.

Comment: @Ed S. I updated the question to show that I initialized count...I just forgot to put it in. Also I'm not sure how to change the headers...from what they taught us in class I think I have to use the first 2, and from what I've researched, I need the last 1 to get exit() to work>

Comment: @Ed S. When I remove the <stdlib> header, I get this error: Error   [1098] C:\Program Files\HI-TECH Software\PICC\9.82\sources\exit.c; 4. conflicting declarations for variable "_exit"

Comment: To diagnose the problem, at the end of your program, you can set PORTD back to input (`TRISD=0xff;`) and add a delay of 2 seconds. Look what happens

Comment: @Wimmel The led blinks 6 times then stays off for 2s, then loops back to blinking.

Comment: Maybe the program restarts. Most programs for pic microcontroller i have seen contain a infinite loop. So, instead of trying to stop the execution, why not adding something like `while(true){}` at the end of the program, so that the led can't blink anymore ?

Comment: I think I found the answer here: [What happens when an embedded program finishes?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/30830/what-happens-when-an-embedded-program-finishes)

Comment: @francis Just tried the while, the same result...the led blinks 6 times then stops for 2s, then repeats.

Comment: @Wimmel : so the program is expected to restart ! An alternative to the infine loop is to call `sleep()` : this will stop the execution until something wakes up the microcontroller, thus stopping the led from blinking. And it will save energy !

Comment: @Keegs : sorry, it is not `while(true){}`, it is `while(1){}`.... And could you try to remove the `abort` command, to test the infinite `while` loop ?

Comment: And, to disable the Watch Dog Timer, you can add `#pragma config WDT=OFF` or [`__CONFIG( WDTE_OFF );`](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/47040/how-do-you-set-the-configuration-bits-for-a-pic-16f1829-in-mplab-x) since you are using htc

Comment: @Wimmel So this is the lab question: Design and implement a method to stop the LED from flashing after the program has started (i.e. while the program is running). And my lab demonstrator said I must use an if else statement and then exit the program ...And I am wondering now if exiting the program is possible to do in a simple way (without messing with the watchdog), or do I just need to make an infinite loop afterwards to keep the led off?

Comment: @francis I actually tried both. Thanks anyway. And the sleep() function needs #include<unistd.h>, but I get this error: Error   [141] C:\Users\Keegs\Desktop\Lab & Proj Design\uP labs\labs\ledblink_home.c; 3.19 can't open include file "unistd.h": No such file or directory

Comment: My fault again...it is [`SLEEP()`](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/47071/pic16-how-does-one-enter-sleep-mode-using-c) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code successfully called the sleep function and exited the infinite loop (Thanks to @francis):

```
#include <htc.h>
#include <pic16f877.h>

#define _XTAL_FREQ 4e6
#define SLEEP() asm("sleep")

int main(void){
    int count = 0;
    int max_count = 6;
    TRISD = 0xBF;
    while(count<max_count){
        count++;
        PORTD   = 0x40;
        __delay_ms(500);
        PORTD   = 0x00;
        __delay_ms(500);
    }
    SLEEP();
}
```